# ENOTFOUND error when using http.request() but http.get() working

Tags: node.js, http, get

I have this strange error with NodeJS where I am trying to do a simple GET request.
This works for me:

```
   http.get('http://54.241.239.69:8332/', function(res){
            var str = '';
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                   str += chunk;
             });

            res.on('end', function () {
                 //console.log(str);
                 clientRes.send(str);
            });
      });
```

However, when trying to do the same with a `request` like this:

```
const options = {
    hostname: 'http://54.241.239.69',
    port: 8332,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET'
  }

  const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

    res.on('data', (d) => {
      process.stdout.write(d)
    })
  })

  req.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error(error)
  })

  req.end()
```

it gives me a `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://54.241.239.69 http://54.241.239.69:8332` error.

Why does `get()` works but not `request()`?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hostname` doesn't take protocol. So it will be just `54.241.239.69`.

Also, you may need to change `https` module to `http` as your link is has `http` protocol.

```
const options = {
    hostname: '54.241.239.69',
    port: 8332,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET'
}
```

**Note:** ENOTFOUND is a DNS error, that means it cannot resolve the hostname.

Comment: Also, `host` and `hostname` are aliases.

Comment: As you can see I am a new user, Please accept the answer if it worked. :-)